# Owner based Authorization

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I'm trying to make authorization based on owner of post. I store in one of post values owner of post. How do I allow only this author to edit only his post. Basic authentication restricts only for logged users, but not for author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do this in your controller function for editing.
In case a post is being edited, first fetch the post being edited and check the id in the field against the value returned by in $this->Auth->user('id') (assuming you're using AuthComponent).

If they're the same, proceed with whatever your editing logic is. If not, you'll probably want to set a flash message (notifying the user that he/she isn't allowed to edit) and then redirect back to somewhere.